# OnsenUI 2 carousel automatically scrolls to first items on page scroll event

Tags: android, ios, angular, carousel, onsen-ui2

I am developing a website in Angular 2 and have used Onsen UI carousel (Horizontal direction) in it. It is set to have multiple items by using item-width attribute.

This works as expected on desktop browsers.

On mobile devices (Android / iPhone), however, we noticed that if we scroll the page down and move up, then carousel list is automatically scrolled left to first item.

I have tried to search over documentation of OnsenUI but have not been able to find solution for it. Please recommend.